# When can we factor $N$ efficiently with a representation $N^2=a^2+b^2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers

Here :

[Can the sum of two squares be used to factor large numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3066531/can-the-sum-of-two-squares-be-used-to-factor-large-numbers?noredirect=1#comment6324532_3066531)

an idea to factor a large number $N=a^2+b^2$ is shown.

> Under which conditions does a representation $$N^2=u^2+v^2$$ exist , such that $\gcd(N,\gcd(u,v))$ is a non-trivial factor of $N$ ?

I guess this is the case, when $N$ has at least one prime factor of the form $4k+1$ and is not a prime power, but I am not sure whether this is true and how it can be proven.

Comment: To enumerate all the ways such that $M = u^2+v^2$ It suffices to know that for $k$ the order of $p \bmod 4$ then $p^k = a^2+b^2$ in a unique way, then write $M= 2^c \prod_{j=1}^J p_j \prod_{i=1}^I q_i^{2e_i+d_i} $ where $p_j,q_i$ are primes $\equiv 1$ and $3 \bmod 4$ and $d_i \in \{0,1\}$

Comment: Maybe it will get the attention it deserves if it were posted on math overflow.